# Rxjs condition error flow

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise, rxjs

I'm essentially creating a transaction. A simplification would be described as follows:

1) Make a promise call.
2) If error and error.code === "ConditionalCheckFailedException", ignore the error and continue the stream with no changes.
3) If error, stop stream.

The following give me 1 and 3. I would like to continue on with the stream if I have a certain exception. Is that possible?
...

At the moment, I have:

```
//... stream that works to this point
.concatMap((item) => {
    const insertions = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(AwsCall(item))
        .catch(e => {
            if (e.code === "ConditionalCheckFailedException") {
                return item
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        });
    return insertions.map(() => item);
})
.concat // ... much the same
```

Comment: thank you - was translating from real code and missed a variable.

Comment: insertions is a promise, right? but not a regular promise,  because regular promises don't have a `map` method ... what does `insertions.map` do? how does it relate to the promise that `insertions` is?

Comment: yes, the AWS call was has a .promise() appended as it returns. "insertions" is an Rx.Observable.fromPromise.

Comment: looking at [this documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catchproto.md) it looks like you're using the *observable* `.catch` incorrectly ... i.e the example does `return Rx.Observable.throw(e);` or `return Rx.Observable.just(42);`

Comment: Try using the promise `catch` not the observable one, i.e. chain the call right onto `AwsCall(…)` not onto `fromPromise(…)`. Your code looks correct from a promise perspective

Comment: Even returning a Rx.Observable.throw(e) and Rx.Observable.just) in the "right" places results in a short-circuit and an error in the subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

So `catch` wants a function which delivers a new Observable.

Instead, use this:

```
//... stream that works to this point
.concatMap((item) => {
  const insertions = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(AwsCall(item))
    .catch(e => e.code === "ConditionalCheckFailedException"
      ? Rx.Observable.of(item)
      : Rx.Observable.throw(e)
    )
    /* depending on what AwsCall returns this might not be necessary: */
    .map(_ => item)
  return insertions;
})
.concat // ... much the same
```

Source: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch